# Why is my ubuntu 22.04 update and upgrade taking longer than expected

Tags: upgrade, updates

I am new to linux and ubuntu I just started using it as I have had enough of windows so I have installed and delete ubuntu several times these days as I am learning php, html so I want host my own local site and test my code so I want to have a real fell about a server control panel. Recently ubuntu is misbehaving and not working as it used to be so I will need some help, first uefi is not coming up when I want to install ubuntu from usb from bios but first it wasn't like that, now update and upgrade is taking longer than expected at first it was talking about 8 minutes to complete now it's getting worst as I am writing my machine is still downloading updates and upgrades since 10 am Ghana time now it's 2:45 pm @ 75%. I have switched servers from Ghana to US but it's not working, I have changed servers dns to Google's public dns but still not working and anytime I try to install a server control panel like virtualmin or ispconfig will take about 40 hours but it wasn't like that previously.now I am confused and I don't know what to do, yesterday I installed windows 10 and it worked smoothly I downloaded all updates fast with out any problems.
This is my setup.
Desktop: esprimo-c710
Processor: Core i5-34
Ram: 4gb
Hdd: 320gb
Ubuntu desktop 22.04.

Comment: If you are asking "*Do the Ubuntu mirrors throttle requests?*" No, they don't.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: What are the results of `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8`? Only need to see the `time=` values.